# OS X app to show GPU usage?

Tags: osx, monitoring, gpu-monitor

As a developer, I push my machine to its limits quite often. It's often quite useful to know how much capacity you're currently using. I use the built in Activity Monitor for checking my CPU usage, but I can't find an option to see GPU usage.

Ideally, I'd like an app that:

- Can show current GPU usage
- Plots said usage on a graph

Optional:

- Show how much energy the GPU is using (probably far fetched)
- Show which tasks are using the GPU

I'm using a 2009 MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.1 with an NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB GPU, if it makes a difference.

I'm fine with either a GUI or CLI, I'm comfortable in a terminal. Is there an app that does these things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least as of macOS 10.14 Mojave, this is now built-in to Activity Monitor. Choose ‘Window → GPU History’ (or hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), personally.  I'm still using version 3 of it on 10.6, but version 4 supports up thru 10.9.  They don't have a screenshot of it, but you can see they support GPU monitoring from [the version history page](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/versionhistory/):

> - Added support for monitoring multiple GPUs.
> - Improved GPU monitoring.

---

To specifically address your other points:

> Plots said usage on a graph

I'm pretty sure my version does this, and if so, I'll add a screenshot when I get home.  If not, then just based on what I know from the rest of their software, then it *should* be graphable in the current version.

> ```
> Show how much energy the GPU is using (probably far fetched)
> ```

I don't know if it shows GPU voltage, but it definitely will show CPU temperature and fan speeds, which should give you a ballpark estimate.  It *does* measure other voltages, so if you have a sensor which can show GPU voltage, it will show it to you.

> ```
> Show which tasks are using the GPU
> ```

This I can't speak to at all.  It shows CPU usage and memory usage, but those are easy pieces of information to get.

---

Here's an example of my CPU menu and general "Sensor" menu. Again, this is version 3, not the current one, but you can see that it has at least basic support for **GPU information** and **power usage**.  The specifics of what you get will be based on what your computer is able to actually measure, but Apple's really good with their sensor placement, plus whatever version 4 adds.

<sub>My machine is a 2008 Mac Pro</sub>

[image: CPU menu][image: Sensor menu]

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer FOSS solutions (what I personally do), you can give [XRG for Mac](https://github.com/mikepj/XRG) a try.

It displays CPU, GPU, memory, battery, temperature, network and disk graphs. And even 2 more not-related to hardware: weather and stocks.